# Is there a version of Buhlmann-Straub credibility that uses an non-fixed $\theta_i$?

Tags: survival, loss-functions

Everything I've read about Buhlmann-Straub credibility assumes a fixed $\theta_i$ (the unknown parameter that $X_{ij}$, the variable of interest, depends on). Does anyone know of a version where theta can vary, say with time?

Comment: Math formatting is accomplished with mathjax, which is basically the same as LaTeX. Numerous tutorials and code-to-symbol lookup tables are available online.